# SQL - Need help in making Queries

Tags: sql

I have these tables in my database:

```
TOY_STORE
 Store_ID(PK)
 Name

TOYS
 Toy_ID(PK)
 Store_ID(FK)
 Name

ORDERED_TOYS
 Ordered_Toy_ID(PK)
 Order_ID(FK)
 Toy_ID(FK)
 Toy_Price_per_unit
 Units

ORDERS
 Order_ID(PK)
 Customer_ID(FK)
 Date  datetime

CUSTOMERS
 Customer_ID(PK)
 Name
```

I need to make 2 queries from these tables:

1- I need to show the total of each `order` from January 2005, showing the fields `Name` from `Costumer`, `Date` from `Orders` and the total of the `order`.

2- I need to show how many units were sold from each `toy` in March 2005, showing the fields `Name` from `Toys`, `Name` from `Toy Store` (and there can be toys not connected to any Toy Store) and how many units were sold.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: **WHAT** database - **which** version?!?!?!?!

Comment: This definitely looks like homework. I would recommend looking here: http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_intro.asp

Comment: I just need to make a SQL query for that. Can be generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stuff isn't rocket science and if you're tasked with creating an app to interact with this database you really will need to know how to write this kind of query.

I'm on a train and I'm bored so...

```
SELECT c.Name, o.Date, SUM(ot.Toy_Price_per_unit*ot.Units) FROM ORDERS o 
JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON o.Customer_ID=c.Customer_ID 
JOIN ORDERED_TOYS ot ON o.Order_ID=ot.Order_ID 
WHERE DATE(o.Date) >= '2005-01-01' 
GROUP BY o.Order_ID;

SELECT t.Name, ts.Name, COUNT(*) FROM TOYS t 
LEFT JOIN TOY_STORE ts ON t.Store_ID=ts.Store_ID 
LEFT JOIN ORDERED_TOYS ot ON t.Toy_ID=ot.Toy_ID 
LEFT JOIN ORDERS o ON ot.Order_ID=o.Order_ID 
WHERE MONTH(o.Date) = 3 
GROUP BY t.Toy_ID, ts.Name;
```

They are written with MySQL in mind, and are **not** tested. Might get you started.

Remember that Stackoverflow is not the appropriate place for questions of this nature. It is not here to teach the fundamentals but to gather questions and answers that are likely to be of use to other people. This question is of almost no use to anyone but you.